# Display object information in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, oop, netbeans

I want to display the object inside the session bean in to the jsp by using the servlet

this my servlet

```
  <form action="profile" method="POST">

       <input  id="User Name" type="text" value="${user.username } " name="userName" /><br>
       <input id="Password" type="text" placeholder="Password"  name="password" value="${user.password}" size="20" /><br>         
       <input id="Name" type="text" placeholder="Name"  name="Name" value="${user.userInfo}" /><br>


    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

the userInfo is a object which contain name..... so how i going to show the object inside the userInfo....... the result of ${user.userInfo} is only return the database refer which is  Database.UserInformation[ id=401 ] how i going to access the item inside the id?
this is my userInformation

@Entity
public class UserInformation implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof UserInformation)) {
        return false;
    }
    UserInformation other = (UserInformation) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Database.UserInformation[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
```

}

and this is my users class

public class Users implements Serializable {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;

 @OneToOne
private UserInformation userInfo;

public UserInformation getUserInfo() {
    return userInfo;
}

public void setUserInfo(UserInformation userInfo) {
    this.userInfo = userInfo;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof Users)) {
        return false;
    }
    Users other = (Users) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Database.Users[ id=" + id + " ]";
}
```

}

Comment: What value you want to get from userInfo. Ex: user.userInfo.value

Comment: i tried before but the input does not show any thing

Comment: Can you show us the UserInfo model?

Comment: Strange maybe your DB is empty try with "${user.userInfo.name}" Should work. See if that user have that values in the DB

Comment: Thank for helping. The DB have no value for name. i solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
${user.userInfo.name}
```

This will give you the value of the userInfo and if it gives you an empty value then check your DB if is empty. Glad it worked.